# How can I create links in the Properties window for a custom control?

Tags: .net, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

In the .NET Framework, there are several controls that list a number of links underneath the property list in the Properties window in the Visual Studio designer. (e.g. TabControl, ComboBox)

I have built a custom control, and I want to create a link on the Properties Window like the TabControl and ComboBox. When the link is clicked, a certain method on my control should be called.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom designer for your control and override the `Verbs` property. The first time your override is called, create a `DesignerVerbCollection` and populate it. Return the collection on each subsequent call.

Edit: By the way, you create the designer by deriving from `System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner` and you apply it to your class by putting this attribute on your class:

```
 [Designer(MyControlDesigner)]
 public class MyControl
 {
    // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [DesignerVerb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.designerverb.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

[devarticles](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Custom-Controls-and-Design-Time-Support-Part-2/3/)

```
public class DirectoryTreeDesigner : ControlDesigner 
{ 

protected override void PostFilterProperties( 
System.Collections.IDictionary properties) 
{ 
     properties.Remove("Nodes"); 
} 

DesignerVerbCollection verbs = new DesignerVerbCollection(); 

public DirectoryTreeDesigner() 
{ 
     // Configure the designer verb collection. 
     string[] drives = System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives(); 

     foreach (string drive in drives) 
     { 
         verbs.Add(new DesignerVerb("Set Drive " + drive, new EventHandler(OnVerb))); 
     } 
} 

public override DesignerVerbCollection Verbs 
{ 
     get { return verbs; } 
} 

protected void OnVerb(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the selected drive. 
    char driveLetter = ((DesignerVerb)sender).Text[10]; 

    // Adjust the associated control. 
    ((DirectoryTree)this.Control).Drive = driveLetter; 
}
```

}

Comment: This doesn't help me. I asked how to display a link under the property grid, like the "Add Tab" and "Remove Tab" links on the TabControl. I did not ask how to create a property for the control.